# is this bit field of size one actually overflowing when assigning 1?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, integer-overflow

I have written some code with bit fields that I thought should work, but it seems like GCC disagrees. Did I miss something or did I actually find a bug in GCC?

After simplifying my code, the testcase is quite simple. I'm assigning the integer literal `1` to a bitfield that has a size of one bit:

```
typedef struct bitfield
{
    int bit : 1;
} bitfield;

bitfield test()
{
    bitfield field = {1};
    return field;
}
```

If I compile this with GCC 6.2.1 (same with 5.4.0), I get the following warning (with -pedantic):

```
gcc -fPIC test.c -pedantic -shared
test.c: In function ‘test’:
test.c:8:23: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
     bitfield field = {1};
                       ^
```

The strange thing is: When I replace -pedantic with -Woverflow, the warning disappears.

I don't get any warnings with clang.

Comment: Think: which values can a single bit, 2s complement integer hold?

Comment: @Olaf Note: An `int` bit-field might not be  implemented as a signed field.  C11 dr §6.7.2 5

Comment: @chux: Ehm, yes. But here it apparently **is**. Btw.: I'm not sure if that is about the underlying (container) type or the field itself. I already thought about commenting on Barmar's answer. Feel free to add the comment, I'm seriously not sure how to interpret that, I use `bool` for single bits - if I use them at all.

Comment: @chux I use this code with C89, so there is no bool available. I did not mention C89 though, because I think the underlying principle of the overflow applies to all C standards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `unsigned int` for this bit field. A 1-bit signed number can only hold `0` and `-1`.

```
typedef struct bitfield
{
    unsigned int bit : 1;
} bitfield;
```

Comment: Now I understand. The one bit is the sign of the 1 bit signed number. I hadn't thought the answer would be that simple, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> is this bit field of size one actually overflowing when assigning 1?

Maybe.  It is implementation defined.

---

This is a place in C where `int` and `signed int/signed` may **differ**.

`unsigned int bit : 1;` can hold the value 0 or 1.

Assuming 2's complement machine ...

`signed int bit : 1;` can hold the value 0 or -1
`signed bit : 1;` can hold the value 0 or -1

`int bit : 1;` can hold the value 0 or 1 **or** 0 or -1

> Each of the comma-separated multisets (`int, signed, or signed int`) designates the same type, **except that for bitfields**, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier `int` designates the same type as `signed int` or the same type as `unsigned int`.  C11 dr §6.7.2 5

---

Using `unsigned` removes ambiguities.

Comment: This is the most bizarre quote in the entire C11 standard. Type int is always signed except for bit-fields. Great...

Comment: @2501  There _may_ be other C parts were they differ - I do not know of any.   It is surprising if not out-right bizarre.  I suspect it has to deal with non-2's complement machines.  Should `int bit:1` hold 0 or -0, or 0 or trap, or hmmm.

Comment: For single bits, it is best to use `bool` anyway. It is an unsigned integer type with values `0` and `1` only. Also many (if not all) implementations use just a single byte. Re the type: Yes, it is weird and one more reason to think twice before using bit-fields at all. However, the implementation in question seems to use a signed integer, thus the warning.

Comment: As a sidenote: gcc has the option `-fsigned-bitfields` and its counterpart, so it **can** be forced to behave as one expects it.